# How to move a UI GameObject using Mouse Position in 3D World Space?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouse, game-engine

I have been trying to experiment with moving UI Elements using the position of the mouse, Trying to make it behave like a cursor. I was able to move the Element when the Canvas Render Mode was set to **"Screen Space"**. I was able to clamp it within the Canvas as well.

But I want it to work when the Canvas Render Mode is **"World Space"** as well. If I use the same code that I used for the Screen Space, the Element leaves its boundaries and gets messed up as the angles are being varied.

I really need help. Any clue how to do it?

You can view how the scene looks in this image below. : https://img.techpowerup.org/200624/screen.png

*If Raycasting is the solution, can someone please help me out and provide a snippet of code or something.*

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is probably [`RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle.html)

> Transform a screen space point to a position in world space that is on
> the plane of the given `RectTransform`.
>
> The cam parameter should be the camera associated with the screen
> point. For a `RectTransform` in a `Canvas` set to **Screen Space - Overlay**
> mode, **the cam parameter should be `null`**.
>
> When `ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle` is used from within an event
> handler that provides a `PointerEventData` object, the correct camera
> can be obtained by using `PointerEventData.enterEventData` (for hover
> functionality) or `PointerEventData.pressEventCamera` (for click
> functionality). This will automatically use the correct camera (or
> `null`) for the given event.

You didn't post your code but you could probably use it in a [`GraphicRaycaster.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.GraphicRaycaster.Raycast.html). Something like

```
GraphicRaycaster m_Raycaster;
PointerEventData m_PointerEventData;
EventSystem m_EventSystem;
Canvas canvas;

void Start()
{
    //Fetch the Raycaster from the GameObject (the Canvas)
    m_Raycaster = GetComponent<GraphicRaycaster>();
    //Fetch the Event System from the Scene
    m_EventSystem = GetComponent<EventSystem>();
    canvas = GetComponnet<Canvas>();

    //Set up the new Pointer Event
    m_PointerEventData = new PointerEventData(m_EventSystem);
}

void Update()
{
    //Check if the left Mouse button is clicked
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {
        //Set the Pointer Event Position to that of the mouse position
        m_PointerEventData.position = Input.mousePosition;

        //Create a list of Raycast Results
        List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();

        //Raycast using the Graphics Raycaster and mouse click position
        m_Raycaster.Raycast(m_PointerEventData, results);

        //For every result returned, output the name of the GameObject on the Canvas hit by the Ray
        foreach (RaycastResult result in results)
        {
            Debug.Log("Hit " + result.gameObject.name);

            // until here it was the API example for GraphicRaycaster.Raycast
            // Now get the first hit object
            var rect = result.gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
            if(rect)
            {
                // check which camera to get (main or null for ScreenSpace Overlay)
                var camera = canvas.renderMode == RenderMode.ScreenSpaceOverlay ? null : Camera.main;
                if(RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle(rect, result.screenPosition, camera, out var worldPosition))
                {
                    cursor3D.transform.position = worldPosition;
                    cursor3D.transform.rotation = result.gameObject.transform.rotation;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Especially note also

- Attach this script to your `Canvas` GameObject.
- Also attach a `GraphicsRaycaster` component to your canvas by clicking the Add Component button in the Inspector window.
- Also make sure you have an `EventSystem` in your hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did try this code out, and it was a click-based cursor control. So I removed the if statement that checks the left click. But then this method is still not being accurate enough. The Red Element does get out of the canvas at times, but it is far better than the code I had. Is there some better solution that can help me clamp the values accurately. 

Im trying to use this to create an interactable laptop within a 3D game. If you have any alternate solution that I should be looking into, Please do let me know. Once again, Thanks :)